# Perl and Postgresql UTF8 problems with directories

Tags: perl, postgresql, utf-8

I am having trouble with directory names with UTF8 characters in them on a Mac (10.11.2) with Perl 5.22 and Postgresql (9.4).  Text encoding in Postgresql is set to UTF8.

If I have a directory name with a non-ascii UTF8 character in it I can chdir() to that directory if the directory name is read in by the Perl script or inserted into a string in the Perl script.  If I insert this name into a PG table and read it back out (SELECT dirname FROM utfdirs) I can't chdir to that directory.  However, the on screen printed strings are identical, a Perl cmp test on the two strings reports they are identical, and guess_encoding() reports both are UTF8.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl5.22  
use strict;
use Cwd;
use DBI;
use Encode;
use Encode qw/from_to/;
use Encode::Detect;
use Encode::Guess;
use Encode::UTF8Mac;
#
Encode::Guess->add_suspects(qw/utf-8-mac/);
#
my $dbname = 'test';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=localhost");
$dbh->do("SET client_min_messages TO WARNING");
#
my $homeDir = '/Users/jldasch';
chdir($homeDir) or die "Cannot cd to [$homeDir]\n";
opendir(D,".");
my @tdlist = sort grep(/(Lambda?)|(Delta?)/,readdir(D));
closedir(D);
$dbh->do("DELETE FROM utfdirs");
my $ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO utfdirs (dirname) VALUES (?)");
foreach my $d (@tdlist) {
    chdir($homeDir);
    my $ok = chdir($d) ? 1 : 0;
    my $fp = "${homeDir}/${d}";
    printf("%2d %s\n",$ok,$fp);
    $ins->execute($fp);
}
my $rset = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT dirname FROM utfdirs ORDER BY dirname");
my $i = 0;
foreach my $r (@$rset) {
    my $dbdir = $r->[0];
    my $pdir = ${homeDir} . '/' . $tdlist[$i++];
    print "$r->[0]  $pdir\n";
    my $encPerl = guess_encoding($pdir);
    my $encDb = guess_encoding($dbdir);
    print "Perl Encoding [$encPerl->{Name}]\n";
    print "Db   Encoding [$encDb->{Name}]\n";
    unless ( chdir($dbdir) ) {
    print "Cannot CD to DbDir [$dbdir]\n";
    print "DbDir and PerlDir Match\n" if ($dbdir eq $pdir)
}
exit;
```

The output:

```
bash-3.2$ ./utfstuff2.pl 
1 /Users/jldasch/DeltaΔ
1 /Users/jldasch/Lambdaλ
/Users/jldasch/DeltaΔ  /Users/jldasch/DeltaΔ
Perl Encoding [utf8]
Db   Encoding [utf8]
Cannot CD to DbDir [/Users/jldasch/DeltaΔ]
DbDir and PerlDir Match
/Users/jldasch/Lambdaλ  /Users/jldasch/Lambdaλ
Perl Encoding [utf8]
Db   Encoding [utf8]
Cannot CD to DbDir [/Users/jldasch/Lambdaλ]
DbDir and PerlDir Match
```

So at the level I have checked so far Perl is telling me the strings are the same (both cmp and guess_encoding()), they print the same, but they are not the same.

How do I convert the UTF8 string returned by Postgresql to a string which is accepted (in Perl) as a valid directory name for chdir()?

Comment: There is a module Encode::UTF8Mac which appears to solve this.  `my $macOkDir = Encode::decode('utf-8-mac',$dbDir)`

Comment: Use `Devel::Peek` to compare strings with encoding problems. Please show output for `$dbdir` and `$pdir` with `Devel::Peek::Dump`

Comment: Is the string the exact same bytes? I'm wondering if there's a precomposed-vs-decomposed-representation issue here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module Encode::UTF8Mac which appears to solve this.

```
my $macOkDir = Encode::decode('utf-8-mac',$dbDir)
```

– John Daschbach